# How to bind value from combobox created from one entity to another

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

I am trying to binding data from one entity to another.

First entity `Car`:

```
public class Car {

@Id
private Long carId;
private String carName;
private Long brandId;
.
.
.

}
```

refers to the second entity `Brand`:

```
public class Brand {

@Id
private Long brandId;
private String brandName;
.
.
.

}
```

In the view class `CarDetailView` I am using **combobox** with `brand names`, but binder is seted to `Car` entity

```
public class CarDetailView extends Div implements BeforeEnterObserver {

   private ComboBox<String> brandNames;
   private BeanValidationBinder<Car> binder;

   private void createBasicLayout(SplitLayout splitLayout) {
        brandNames = new ComboBox<>("Brand name");
        brandNames.setItems(brandRepository.findAllBrandNames()); //function returns all brandNames from database (e.g. Volkswagen, Volvo, Audi, ...)
   }

}
```

So it returns the correct result into the combobox (combobox contains all brand names), but when I choose value from combobox, it can't be binded into the `Car` entity.

The problem is, that I need to get the `brandId` from text in combobox and set it into the `Car` entity with `binder`.

I tried to use `pairs`:

```
private ComboBox<Pair<Long, String>> brandNames;
```

where I have seted the `brandId` (left side) and `brandName` (right side), but it still can't bind it into the `Car`, because it throw an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property type 'java.lang.Long' doesn't match the field type 'com.vaadin.flow.internal.Pair<java.lang.Long, java.lang.String>'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

**Working result:**

I used the Simon Martinelli answer:

```
public class CarDetailView extends Div implements BeforeEnterObserver {

   private ComboBox<Brand> brand;
   private BeanValidationBinder<Car> binder;

   private void createBasicLayout(SplitLayout splitLayout) {
        binder = new BeanValidationBinder<>(Car.class);
        binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

      
        brand = new ComboBox<>("Brand name");
        brand.setItems(brandRepository.findAllBrands()); //function returns all Brands

        Map<Long, Brand> brandMap = new HashMap<>()
        {
           {
            put(2000000L, new Brand(2000000L, "Audi"));
            put(2000001L, new Brand(2000001L, "Volvo"));
           }
        };

        binder.forField(brand) //Line 251
        .withConverter(new Converter<Brand, Long>() { 
            @Override  superclass
            public Result<Long> convertToModel(Brand value, ValueContext context) {
                return Result.ok(value == null ? null : value.getBrandId());
            }

            @Override superclass
            public Brand convertToPresentation(Long value, ValueContext context) {
                return brandMap.get(value);
            }
        }).bind(Car::getBrandId, Car::setBrandId);
        
   }

   brand.setItemLabelGenerator(brand-> brand.getBrandName());

}
```

Comment: You need a Converter when binding it, see: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/tools/ce/components/collaboration-binder/#converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Brand` in the `ComboBox` instead of a `String`.

Then you can implement `setItemLabelGenerator` to display what you need.

See the documentation:
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/combo-box/#custom-item-presentation

Edit:

You have to use a converter to bind the id of the Brand

```
binder.forField(brand)
        .withConverter(new Converter<Brand, Long>() {
            @Override
            public Result<Long> convertToModel(Brand value, ValueContext context) {
                return Result.ok(value == null ? null : value.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public Brand convertToPresentation(Long value, ValueContext context) {
                return brandMap.get(value);
            }
        })
        .bind(Car::getBrandId, Car::setBrandId);
```

The brandMap contains the id of the brand with the corresponding brand.

Comment: Thank you for answer mr. Simon. But it still throwing an exception (check my Edit 2).

Comment: Checkout my updated answer

Comment: Which converter must be used (check image: https://pasteboard.co/bwAgw7t00Nek.png)? Because it doesn't know the Converter. And it throwing an caution on @Override method

Comment: The Vaadin converter

Comment: Thank you, but it still throwing an exception. Now it is NPE on `binder.forField(brand)` row

Comment: what does the NPE say?

Comment: Check my post now please :)

Comment: what is on line 251 in CarDetailView

Comment: `binder.forField(brand)......`

Comment: But this would mean that the binder is null. Have you debugged and checked what's null?

Comment: Yes, the binder was null, I fixed it. Now its working, but combobox contains values like:
`com.example.application.data.entity.Brand@5a52836f[brandId=2000000,brandName=Audi]`. Not only Audi. But binder is working.

Comment: Ok, I got it! I still had to add `brand.setItemLabelGenerator(brand-> brand.getBrandName())`;